# Computation time depends on the matrix elements!

Tags: matrix

Consider these two **lists of** matrices, `matrix` and `matrix2`:

```
n = 150;
m = 50;
matrix = Table[1.0*Sin[i*j*k], {i, 1, n}, {j, 1, n}, {k, 1, n}];
matrix2 = Table[Sin[RandomReal[{0, 1}, {n, n}]], {i, 1, n}];

<< Developer`

PackedArrayQ[matrix]

(*False*)

PackedArrayQ[matrix2]

(*False*)

vector = {IdentityMatrix[n][[1]]}\[Transpose];


Do[
  x1 = Table[#1\[ConjugateTranspose].(matrix[[#2]].#1) &[vector, 
      i], {i, 1, n}];

  , {iterator1, 1, m}] // AbsoluteTiming
(*{1.060000, Null}*)



Do[
  x1 = Table[#1\[ConjugateTranspose].(matrix2[[#2]].#1) &[vector, 
      i], {i, 1, n}];

  , {iterator1, 1, m}] // AbsoluteTiming
(*{0.170000, Null}*)
```

Why does using `matrix2` give the fastest computation time?

Does the speed of matrix multiplication depend on the value of the matrices involved?

Comment: Check `PackedArrayQ[First@matrix]` and `PackedArrayQ[First@matrix2]`

Comment: Try `ByteCount[matrix]` and `ByteCount[matrix2]` - they're not the same size by any means.

Comment: @SimonWoods. Do you mean that each matrix in `matrix2` is packed but it is not the case for the `matrix`?

Comment: Yes exactly that.

Comment: A better check is `{Or @@ PackedArrayQ /@ matrix, And @@ PackedArrayQ /@ matrix2}` :)

Answer (score 1):

First load up the lists of matrices as you define them:

```
n = 150;
m = 50;
matrix = Table[1.0*Sin[i*j*k], {i, 1, n}, {j, 1, n}, {k, 1, n}];
matrix2 = Table[Sin[RandomReal[{0, 1}, {n, n}]], {i, 1, n}];
```

Now let's check the sizes:

```
ByteCount[matrix]
(* 83174488 *)

ByteCount[matrix2]
(* 27024088 *)
```

Very different! Now...

```
<<Developer`
matrix3 = ToPackedArray@matrix;
ByteCount[matrix3]
(* 27000160 *)

matrix4 = ToPackedArray@matrix2;
ByteCount[matrix3]
(* 27000160 *)
```

So now they're the same size in terms of bytes, but is that the end of the story? No, as we can see from a timing comparison:

```
<< GeneralUtilities`
Do[x1 = Table[#1\[ConjugateTranspose].(matrix[[#2]].#1) &[vector, 
      i], {i, 1, n}];, {iterator1, 1, m}] // AccurateTiming

(* 1.148 seconds *)

Do[x1 = Table[#1\[ConjugateTranspose].(matrix2[[#2]].#1) &[vector, 
      i], {i, 1, n}];, {iterator1, 1, m}] // AccurateTiming

(* 0.1814 seconds *)

Do[x1 = Table[#1\[ConjugateTranspose].(matrix3[[#2]].#1) &[vector, 
      i], {i, 1, n}];, {iterator1, 1, m}] // AccurateTiming

(* 0.3711 seconds *)

Do[x1 = Table[#1\[ConjugateTranspose].(matrix4[[#2]].#1) &[vector, 
      i], {i, 1, n}];, {iterator1, 1, m}] // AccurateTiming

(* 0.3087 seconds *)
```

`matrix2` is still the fastest! The same result can be achieved by doing the following, i.e. packing each sub-matrix within the larger list.

```
matrix5 = ToPackedArray[#] & /@ matrix;
ByteCount[matrix5]
Do[x1 = Table[#1\[ConjugateTranspose].(matrix5[[#2]].#1) &[vector, 
      i], {i, 1, n}];, {iterator1, 1, m}] // AccurateTiming

(* 27024088 *)
(* 0.1791 seconds *)
```

Thus, the fastest computation is achieved by packing the individual matrices within each list, which is true for `matrix2` but not for `matrix`.

Comment: It's strange that when you pack `matrix2`, it gets slower!